# How to replace an object in an array with another object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In vue.js I am looking for a way to replace `social` in the array with another object's key with the same value, for example:

```
netTeams: {
            0: {
                social: 'Twitter',
                name: 'Red',
                id: 32,
                group: 'a'
            },
            1: {
                social: 'Twitter',
                name: 'Green',
                id: 33,
                group: 'b'
            }
        }
```

and

```
socials: {
            1: Facebook,
            2: Instagram,
            3: Twitter,
            4: Youtube
        }
```

the result should be

```
netTeams: {
        0: {
            social: 3,
            name: 'Red',
            id: 32,
            group: 'a'
        },
        1: {
            social: 3,
            name: 'Green',
            id: 33,
            group: 'b'
        }
    }
```

I tried a computed property but I get errors. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you add the computed property you tried and the related error please?

Comment: Would be a lot easier if you swapped the keys and values in your `socials` object: `Object.values(netTeams).forEach(v => v.social = socials[v.social]);`

Comment: Or if you dont want to swap the keys and values of `socials`, replace `socials[v.social]);` in @RobbyCornelissen's comment with this `Object.keys(socials).find(key => socials[key] ===  v.social))`

Comment: Actually it would be even simplier if you could make your objects array, instead of objects with indexes as keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is not Vuejs related but a pure javascript question.

To do what you need, you have to:

1. Iterate over your teams to find the set the value for each team
2. Find the correct value by comparing the team name to the socials array values (find by index or get the object key)
3. Return a copy of the team, with the new "social" value you found
4. Wrap everything in a computed property so it's reactive when `netTeams` changes.

See the following snippet for the full code.

> As commented, the code would have been simplier if you could convert your index based objects to actual arrays (i.e. `['Facebook', 'Twitter']` instead of `{0: 'Facebook', 1: 'Twitter'}`).

```html
<html>
<div id="app">
  <pre>{{ socialsWithIndex }}</pre>
</div>

<!-- Don't forget to include Vue from CDN! -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        socials: {
          1: 'Facebook',
          2: 'Twitter',
          3: 'LinkedIn',
        },
        netTeams: {
            0: {
                social: 'Twitter',
                name: 'Red',
                id: 32,
                group: 'a'
            },
            1: {
                social: 'Twitter',
                name: 'Green',
                id: 33,
                group: 'b'
            },
            2: {
                social: 'Facebook',
                name: 'Blue',
                id: 34,
                group: 'c'
            }
        }
      }
    },
    computed: {
      socialsWithIndex() {
        // Transform each team (had to convert to an array)
        return Object.values(this.netTeams).map(team => {
          // Find the socials index from the value. Split into entries to get both key + value
          const [correspondingSocialIndex,] = Object.entries(this.socials).find(([socialIndex, socialName]) => socialName === team.social)

          /* This could work too, if your object keys are always indexes
           * const correspondingSocialIndex = Object.values(this.socials).findIndex(socialName => socialName === team.social)
           */

          // Return a copy of the team, with just the "social" key with the new value
          return {
            ...team,
            social: parseInt(correspondingSocialIndex, 10) // Convert the string key to number
          }
        })
      }
    },
  });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this

```js
const netTeams = {
    0: {
        social: 'Twitter',
        name: 'Red',
        id: 32,
        group: 'a'
    },
    1: {
        social: 'Twitter',
        name: 'Green',
        id: 33,
        group: 'b'
    }
};

const socials = {
            1: 'Facebook',
            2: 'Instagram',
            3: 'Twitter',
            4: 'Youtube',
        };
const reversedSocials = Object.keys(socials).reduce((acc, key) => {
   acc[socials[key]] = Number(key)
   return acc
}, {});
console.log(reversedSocials);

const updated = {}
for ([key, value] of Object.entries(netTeams)) {
   console.log(key)
   updated[key] = {
       ...value,
       social: reversedSocials[value.social],
   }
}

console.log(updated)
```